# Using $\nabla$ in an inertial frame that moves at constant velocity with regards to an inertial frame at rest

Tags: special-relativity

We are currently studying the special relativity and we began with the galilean transformations. And now we are considering the Michelson-Morley Experiment, which somehow will show that phenomenons that have to do with electrodynamics pose a problem to these kinds of transformations (I hope my understanding I correct here, as to why we consider this experiment).

In an arbitrary inertial frame $K$ the wave equation is:

$$\nabla^2 \vec E(\vec r,t)=\frac 1 {c^2}\frac {\partial^2\vec E(\vec r,t)}{\partial t^2}$$

Now we consider another inertial frame $K'$, which moves at constant velocity $\vec v$ relative to $K$ and for simplicity we consider a movement in the x direction. Then we have:

$x'=x-vt$

$y'=y$

$z'=z$

$t'=t$

And $E_x(x,t)=E_x(x' +vt',t')$

For the position derivation we have:

$$\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial x}= \frac{\partial E_x}{\partial x'}\frac{\partial x'}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial E_x}{\partial t'}\frac{\partial t'}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial x'}$$

And for the time derivative:

$$\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial t}= \frac{\partial E_x}{\partial x'}\frac{\partial x'}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial E_x}{\partial t'}\frac{\partial t'}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial x'} -v\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial x'}$$

Can someone explain to me how do we end up with those chain derivations? I don't understand where they come from?

Also what even is the meaning of $\frac {t'}{x}$ derivating time in the moving frame (even though we know that t'=t) with position in the initial frame. Does it have meaning to derivate time with respect to position?

Comment: For the second equation, I think it should be $\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial t}= \frac{\partial E_x}{\partial x'}\frac{\partial x'}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial E_x}{\partial t'}\frac{\partial t'}{\partial t} = -v \frac{\partial E_x}{\partial x'} + \frac{\partial E_x}{\partial t'}$. In any case, are you aware of the [multivariable chain rule](https://math.hmc.edu/calculus/hmc-mathematics-calculus-online-tutorials/multivariable-calculus/multi-variable-chain-rule/)?

Comment: Yes I am, but I fail to see how $x'$ is dependent on time?

Comment: you can argue that $x= x' + vt$ and then the partial time derivative, should only affect the x component.

Comment: Why are you differentiating with respect to x' , shouldn't it be (dE/dx)(dx/dt) + (dE/dt')(dt'/dt) ? As the function E does not explicitly depend on x', rather x. Which is x'+vt'. I could be wrong

Comment: Exactly. But apparently when you express $E_x(x,t)$ as $E_x(x'+vt',t')$ the $x'$ contains the $x$ therefore we have a chain derivation??? Still I don't understand where the chain derivation comes from when you consider the time?